# Writing a Java class for the creation of CardLayouts for my program

Tags: java, cardlayout, variadic-functions

I have a tabbed view in my program and under each tab I have several panels which I rotate between with buttons.  I've decided to implement a CardLayout for each one of these tabs, and given that I have about 7 tabs I decided to write a class to make things a bit neater.  The class is called PanelSystem and it takes in JPanels which have already been created and adds them to a CardLayout.  I will also implement a switchPanel method to move between panels.  So far I have:

```
public class PanelSystem {

JPanel cards;
CardLayout cl;

public PanelSystem(JPanel...panels) {
    // Create Panel with card layout
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

    // Add all the panels to the card system
    for (JPanel p : panels) cards.add(p);

    // Gains access to the card layout?
    cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());

    // Show starting card
    cl.show(cards, *UNIQUE IDENTIFIER*);
}
}
```

Since there are different numbers of JPanels for each tab I had to implement the JPanels...panels line.  I'm not sure if this works correctly yet, but the problem comes at the end of the constructor where I'm trying to show the first card since it doesn't have a unique identifier because of the way I added them.  Any thoughts on how I could fix this??  Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the varargs as if it were an array (which it is, anyway).  How about if you loop through it with a classical for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    cards.add(panels[i], Integer.toString(i));
}
```

then at the end

```
cl.show(cards, "0");
```

Edit: I'm rusty on Swing layouts, can't remember exactly whether you need your identifier to be a String or just any Object, but you should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Andrew!  I didn't know that was how it worked.  So if I did this: 

public PanelSystem(JPanel...panels, String...names)

I would get 2 arrays named panels and names.  The point of this would be to specify a panel followed by a String identifier - would this work?

Comment: Sadly not: only the last argument can be a varargs (otherwise the compiler wouldn't be able to figure out where one finished and the other started, I guess)

Comment: ahh I see.  The only potential problem with the way you showed me is that it might be hard to know what panel the number refers to

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming you didn't mind when building the CardLayout which panel was which, and simply wanted to show the first one.  If you want to give them names, you could set the name as a client property (which is a Map-type functionality in JComponent where you can put anything you want): `panel.setClientProperty("name", "widgetPanel1")` and then within the above code `cards.add(panels[i], panels[i].getClientProperty("name")`

Comment: I don't much like client properties though because they're completely invisible and non-compile-checked. Another alternative would just be to send `String[] names, JPanel[] panels` as your method parameters.